# How should we handle vague questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/908/97) is apparently related to mahjong combinatorics, but is vague. It's generating some close recommendations, with no rationale provided.  It has a comment thread discussing mostly whether to close.

The question is, should this site close questions simply because they are too vague to answer definitively?  On other SE sites, that's not normally a consideration for closure.

Answer (score 6):

The best approach is to request clarification in a comment. Sometimes, for vague questions, I may also try a fairly broad answer that covers several possible interpretations for what the question might mean, but frequently I'll just ask for clarification. If the author doesn't clarify, then it might be worth voting to close as "not a real question," but I tend to try and give the benefit of the doubt and wait a bit before doing that.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I did my best to fix the question, by defining the key term, "made hand," in my answer. Then I tried to answer the question.